# Android signing apk with apksigner using store type Windows-MY

Tags: android, android-11, apksigner, apk-signing

I am trying to use APK Signature Scheme v2 for my app as part of targeting Android 11 changes. Until now, I was using jarsigner to sign the apk using storetype Windows-MY (type of key store on Windows) on my build machine like this:

```
jarsigner -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -storetype "Windows-MY" -signedjar temp.apk  myapp.apk
```

Now I want to use apksigner to sign the apk, but I am struggling to find a way to use store type Windows-MY with apksigner.
Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing what you've tried and where you've "struggled".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the flag you're looking for in apksigner is `--ks-type`.